# Why do I get build errors when attempting to build a .NetCore 3.1 class library with EntityFrameworkCore in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, nuget, visual-studio-2019

I've got a .Net Core 3.1 created in Visual Studio 2019 (C# .Net Core library).
I'm attempting to add EntityFrameworkCore thru NuGet package manager to the project.
When attempting to add I got some compatibility errors.

So we created the projects and added EntityFrameworkCore on a different system.
When attempting to build those project in Visual Studio 2019 on my system, I get the
following errors:

[image: Errors in Visual Studio 2019]

This is a snapshot of the .Net and .NetCore runtime and sdks installed on the machine:
[image: Installed runtime and SDKs]

**Here are the results from dotnet restore:**
(Partial Listing)

> Foo.WPFApp>dotnet restore   Determining projects to restore...  :
> warning NU1701: Package 'System.ComponentModel.Annotations 5.0.0' was
> restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1,
> .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7,
> .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2,
> .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework
> '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'. This package may not be fully compatible
> with your project. [Foo.WPFApp\Bar.WPFApp.sln]  : error NU1202:
> Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.0 is not compatible with
> netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.0 does not support any target
> frameworks. [Foo.WPFApp\Bar.WPFApp.sln]  : error NU1202: Package
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions 5.0.0 is not compatible
> with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions 5.0.0 does not support any
> target frameworks. [Foo.WPFApp\Bar.WPFApp.sln]  : error NU1202:
> Package Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory 5.0.0 is not compatible
> with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package
> Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory 5.0.0 does not support any target
> frameworks. [Foo.WPFApp\Bar.WPFApp.sln]  : error NU1202: Package
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection 5.0.0 is not compatible with
> netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection 5.0.0 does not support any
> target frameworks. [Foo.WPFApp\Bar.WPFApp.sln]  : error NU1202:
> Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 5.0.0 is not compatible with
> netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package
> Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 5.0.0 does not support any target
> frameworks. [Foo.WPFApp\Bar.WPFApp.sln]  : error NU1202: Package

**Here are the results from a dotnet build:**
(Partial Listing)

> Determining projects to restore... ....csproj : warning NU1701:
> Package 'System.ComponentModel.Annotations 5.0.0' was restored using
> '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2,
> .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1,
> .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of
> the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'. This package
> may not be fully compatible with your project.
> [Foo.WPFApp\Bar.WPFApp.sln] ....csproj : error NU1202: Package
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.0 is not compatible with
> netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.0 does not support any target
> frameworks. [Foo.WPFApp\Bar.WPFApp.sln] ....csproj : error NU1202:
> Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions 5.0.0 is not
> compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions 5.0.0 does not support any
> target frameworks. [Foo.WPFApp\Bar.WPFApp.sln] ....csproj : error
> NU1202: Package Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory 5.0.0 is not
> compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package
> Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory 5.0.0 does not support any target
> frameworks. [Foo.WPFApp\Bar.WPFApp.sln] ....csproj : error NU1202:
> Package Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection 5.0.0 is not
> compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection 5.0.0 does not support any
> target frameworks. [Foo.WPFApp\Bar.WPFApp.sln] ....csproj : error

Can someone help me identify the issue and fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** Try to [clean nuget caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) first or just delete all cache files under `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\.nuget\packages`.

**2)** disable any installed vs third party extensions under **Extensions**-->**Manage Extensions**-->**Installed**

**Or** use [devenv /safemode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019) to start a initial vs to test whether the issue happens again.

**Also**, please do not forget to delete every `bin` and `obj` folder before you install the nuget package.

**If** your VS2019 version is not `16.8.X`, please update it because `NET5.0` is applied since `16.8`.

**Besides**, try to create a new net core app and then test whether the issue happens again.

Comment: Issue resolved -thx. I went through steps 1) & 2). It looks like something was cached somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I removed my previous answer since it was not valid.

> This is compiled in Visual Studio 2019. It worked on 1 machine. When we brought solution over to another machine it did not work. Packages: EntityFrameworkCore, .SQL, and .Tools

Try cleaning `bin/` and `obj/` folders before recompiling the project in the machine where it's failing.

Try to compile it directly from the command line as well, using `dotnet build`.

Comment: tried both options. Same results. I updated my version of VS 2019 to 16.8.2(latest).  I just loaded on a different machine and it builds fine. Is there something cached/corrupted in my environment somewhere?

Comment: If you do `dotnet --info`, can you see a .NET 3.1.x SDK installed?

Comment: Check post for installed runtime & sdks.

Comment: There's something we're missing here. Can you provide the output of `dotnet restore` (and `dotnet build` if no errors are found in the restore step) after removing bin/ and obj/ folders again?